# How to edit "Reference Resolution" by script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change `Reference Resolutuion` with C# script in real time game, how can I make it?

[image: st]

Because I want to scale my controls with easiest way

[image]
[image]

Comment: 4 years later I found my own question and it helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all the other properties of [`CanvasScaler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.CanvasScaler.html) you can simply use the [`CanvasScaler.referenceResolution`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.CanvasScaler-referenceResolution.html) property in a script like

```
GetComponent<CanvasScaler>().referenceResolution = new Vector2(xSize, ySize);
```

Comment: Should I use Constant `Pixel Size`?

Comment: well before you used `Scale wit Screen Size` so why change it? **If** you switch to `Constant Pixel Size` than you would have to change the `scaleFactor` property instead

Comment: I have `Scale Factor = 1`, how can I edit it with script? In you answer something different

Comment: Your question was originally `How to edit “Reference Resolution” by script in Unity?` .. I showed you a code example that does this. As said **if** you now would rather like to use `Constant Pixel Size` and `scaleFactor` you can do it like described in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56320632/7111561) ... however it is actually not exactly what you asked for in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set reference resolution, but can caculate and set the **Scale Factor** with UISclleMode: **Constant Pixel Size**.

[image]

```
void SetReferenceResolution(Vector2 m_ReferenceResolution,float m_MatchWidthOrHeight = 1f)
{
    private const float kLogBase = 2;
    float logWidth = Mathf.Log(screenSize.x / m_ReferenceResolution.x, kLogBase);
    float logHeight = Mathf.Log(screenSize.y / m_ReferenceResolution.y, kLogBase);
    float logWeightedAverage = Mathf.Lerp(logWidth, logHeight, m_MatchWidthOrHeight);
    GetComponent<Canvas>().scaleFactor = Mathf.Pow(kLogBase, logWeightedAverage);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I got it, can you write full script for 1 object?  I can't exlain what did you write. (I don't see code like  `scale.x = enteredNumber * 10;`)

Comment: `You cannot set reference resolution` .. why not?  (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56329567/7111561))

Comment: Answer is incorrect, you *can* set reference resolution using derHugo's answer

Answer (score 0):

> UI Scale Mode: `Constant Pixel Size`

Simple template:

```
public class Scale : MonoBehaviour {

    public float scale = 1f; // 1 by default

    public void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<Canvas>().scaleFactor = scale;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use `GetComponent` in every frame! Why using this in `Update` at all?